# How to include JSON in the form field using AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I'm trying to use an AFHTTPRequestOperation (via an AFHTTPRequestOperationManager) to transmit some information (say, "foo = bar") to an backend expecting JSON, using a setup like this:

```
- (void) postTest {
NSString *completePath = @"https://httpbin.org/post";
NSDictionary *dataToJSONfy = @{@"foo":@"bar"};
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: dataToJSONfy options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:completePath parameters:nil];
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
[self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"... success! %@", JSON);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"... failure! Error: %@", error);
}];

[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Which shows up like this

```
{
args =     {
};
data = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
files =     {
};
form =     {
};
headers =     {
    [...]
};
json =     {
    foo = bar;
};
origin = [...];
url = "http://httpbin.org/post";
}
```

**Question:** what would I need to change in order to include my information ("foo = bar;") in the 'form =' section of the body rather than the 'json =' bit?

Comment: dont get your restion. so do you NOT want to include json but formdata?

Comment: I want to include valid JSON (e.g. some server response stored earlier) in the post, but as per API specification, everything's supposed to be located under the 'form = {};' part. So I guess I want JSON as formdata.

Comment: wrote you an answer.. just dont put the json in the body but use a string as intermediate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to include valid JSON (e.g. some server response stored earlier) in the post, but as per API specification, everything's supposed to be located under the 'form = {};' part. So I guess I want JSON as formdata.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: dataToJSONfy options:kNilOptions error:&error];

//new!
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{'Form': '%@'}, jsonString]; //! not 100% what you want. I stick with valid JSON here
NSData *bodyData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:completePath parameters:nil];
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:bodyData]; //!
```

Comment: I didn't get the question, but this cannot work since the body is not JSON (_bodyData_), but the Content-Type pretends it is. It's no known MIME type either.

Comment: it is what he wanted. that all ;) I get it isnt valid json

Comment: I would urlencode it make it application/x-www-form-urlencoded but I think this is indeed what he wants in a way

Comment: If it should be forma data, the Content-Type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or omitted, since this is the default), and the JSON parameter needs to properly encoded (which is a pain to get right). But I guess, the server can accept JSON, and it's just to figure out how to compose it.

Comment: If it's actually something like `{form=<some JSON>}`, then this would require a custom Content-Type. Perhaps a JSON: `{"form": <JSON>}`?

Comment: I made it {form: 'JSON'}

Comment: Thanks for your efforts & patience, everyone! We ended up doing pretty much what's suggested here, creating a `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and adding it to the request body with Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, ultimately leaving it to the backend to re-create the JSON. Marking this as correct, as it seems that this the most viable workaround for what was probably a pretty silly problem to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

first you need to declare nsdictionary  block just after the postTest method like

```
    __block NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

and in success block you should use

```
dict=[NSJSONSerlization JSONObjectWithData:JSON options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"... success! %@", dict);
```